# Using Eventbus or Props Dilemma in Vue.js Template

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component, vuex

I have a mainpage that calls all template with appropriate props, say

```
<sideBar :menu="menu"></sideBar>
<topBar></topbar>
<mainContent><mainContent>
```

the problem is I have a nested data object to be called which naturally best implemented with parent-> children scheme like this :

```
main page-> sideBar -> topBar -> mainContent
```

because the nested object is like following  :

```
menu:{topLevelA:{midLevelA1:'lowContentA1'},
                {midLevelA2:'lowContentA2'},
      topLevelB:{midLevelB1:'lowContentB1'}}
```

naturally if using props, I can easily pass to children and grandchildren, but the downside, it's hard to tracked down the template design, it looks messy and scattered in several places, unlike single page as I have now.

I can opt for a mainpage with the same level of children by using emit event or even Vuex, but that just seem unnatural.. hmmm.

Possibly any better way?

Edit for clarity:

```
<template>
  <div class="window">
    <div class="window-content">
      <div class="pane-group">
        <sidebar-page-view :custList="custList"></sidebar-page-view>
        <div class="pane">
          <topbar-header-view :custMenu="custMenu"></topbar-header-view>
          <window-pane-view :content="content"></window-pane-view>
          <div class="toolbar toolbar-footer">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- Window Content Ends -->
```

Versus:

```
<template>
  <div class="window">
    <div class="window-content">
      <div class="pane-group">
        <sidebar-page-view :custList="custList"></sidebar-page-view>
        <div class="pane">
</template>

<template>
          <topbar-header-view :custMenu="custMenu"></topbar-header-view>
          <window-pane-view :content="content"></window-pane-view>
</template>

<template>
          <window-pane-view :content="content"></window-pane-view>
          <div class="toolbar toolbar-footer">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- Window Content Ends -->
 </template>
```

Data Object:

```
CustomerList A-CustomerA Menu 1-Content 1
                               -Content 2
              -CustomerA Menu 2
              -CustomerA Menu 3 -Content 1
                                -Content 2
CustomerLust B-
              ...
```

It's hierarchical in nature, so props flow would be more make sense, with only methods function can be initiated compared to to only one level hierarchical as

```
I have now   _sidebar (custList)   it has to be initiated with eventBus or vuex
            |    
      Main--|-topbar (custMenu)
            |_
              windowPane (content)
```

Comment: Without an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (minimal, but realistic) of what you want to do, it is not possible to answer this question.

Comment: sorry didn't make it clear, edited as above for clarity.

Comment: I would not have a component that opens tags it does not close, as under "Versus".

Comment: Thank you, @RoyJ, it turns out I'm using vuex anyway because it is not naturally components inside components of component afterall with the templating, which rising another question, but that's in a different thread.